# c++ Synchronize shared memory when reading

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory

I want to synchronize a `shared_memory_object` for reading `iff` the `shared_memory_object` already exists. This is the code I am using for synchronization with a bool variable.

```
boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object my_shared_mat;
bool mat_ready = true;
while (mat_ready)
{
    try {
        my_shared_mat = boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object(
            boost::interprocess::open_only,  // only open
            "shared_mat",                    // name
            boost::interprocess::read_only); // read-only mode
        mat_ready = false;
    }
    catch (boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception &ex) {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
        mat_ready = true;
    }
}

boost::interprocess::mapped_region region(my_shared_mat, boost::interprocess::read_only);
```

If the shared memory exists, I do not have any problems, the data is shared among the processes, but if the shared memory is not present the program crashes at the mapped_region call.

Comment: The code you've shown can't possibly get to the `mapped_region` call unless the object exists. I suggest you show your real code.

Comment: I am creating the object in another process. I want to know how can I create the share memory for reading in this file if the process has not been created yet. If the shared memory was not created it will throw an exception, so I put the while(mat_ready) to account for that. But, if I do it, it crashes when calling mapped_region.

Comment: @JonathanPotter there is the race condition if the server is still in the process of creating the mapped area (resizing it etc.). Yes the code doesn't show it, but it also doesn't show synchronization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to synchronize with another process, use a synchronization primitive: [condition variable](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/named_condition_any.html) with a [mutex](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/named_condition_any.html):

```
#include <boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/named_mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/scoped_lock.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/named_condition.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace bip   = boost::interprocess;
using Mutex     = bip::named_mutex;
using Condition = bip::named_condition;

int main(int argc, char**) {
    Mutex     mx(bip::open_or_create, "shared_mat_mx");
    Condition cv(bip::open_or_create, "shared_mat_cv");

    if (argc>1) { // server
        auto mat = bip::shared_memory_object(bip::create_only, "shared_mat", bip::read_write);
        mat.truncate(10 << 10); // 10kb

        bip::mapped_region region(mat, bip::read_only);

        {
            bip::scoped_lock<Mutex> lk(mx);
            cv.notify_all(); // notify all clients we're there
        }
    } else {
        {
            bip::scoped_lock<Mutex> lk(mx);
            cv.wait(lk); // wait for server signal
        }
        auto mat = bip::shared_memory_object(bip::open_only, "shared_mat", bip::read_only);
        bip::mapped_region region(mat, bip::read_only);

        std::cout << "Mapped the region of size " << region.get_size() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Running a number of clients in the background:

```
for a in {1..10}; do ./sotest& done
```

Makes them all wait. Starting a server:

```
./sotest server
```

Makes them all progress, and they show:

```
Mapped the region of size 10240
```