# Is there an idea to notifiy all the client-process a resource is ready on windows (using C++)?

Tags: c++, windows

I have a shared-memory for other process to read, the number of reading processes could be more than one.

I need a lock, its locked at most of the time. When an updated is applied on the shared-memory, it will be unlocked and quickly locked again.

The reading process could use this lock to receive update-notification. When reading process(es) acquired the lock succesfully, it means the shared-memory is updated. And when reading process failed to lock with result of TIME_OUT, it means there is no update in the shared-memory

When the shared-memory got some update and unlock the lock, **ALL** reading process could acquire the lock

Is there a solution to do this lock ??

Comment: Since they are child processes you could create an inheritable event with [`CreateEventExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createeventexw) and let the children [`WaitForSingleObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject)

Comment: Single writer/multiple readers is a common and long solved problem. Most literature about it will be regarding threads, but it can in almost all cases also be directly translated to processes. What I mean to say is that there are plenty of books and even more information online about this issue and how to solve it. You just need to search for it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49808659/c-synchronize-shared-memory-when-reading

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo I'm sorry, the reader-process are not child processes. They are completely different programs, sharing a shared-memory with a name

Comment: @Jaw109 Ok, my bad. I read too much into "_client-process_". Just a thought: Perhaps they _should_ be child processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different synchronisation primitives for different use cases. A lock is intended to ensure one single access at a time for a resource. But to signal a bunch of readers that some data is ready, you should rather use an event.

From Microsoft doc about [Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/using-event-objects) objects:

> [Applications can use] event objects to prevent several threads from reading from a shared memory buffer while a master thread is writing to that buffer.

You will use [`CreateEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createsemaphoreexw) to create your event object, then `WaitForSingleObject` (or any other waiting function) in your consumer threads, and `SetEvent` to signal that the data is ready. The `ResetEvent` function can be used to signal that consumer threads should not use it.

Comment: Thank you!!!! This is exactly what I need